# How can I find max of multiplication of subtree nodes?

Tags: graph-algorithm

A tree that has N nodes is given. Nodes have weights between -1000 and 1000. That is asked from me is to find maximum of multiplication of subtree nodes. Do you have any idea/algorithm to solve this problem?

For example

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'd just traverse the tree keeping track of a cumulative product until you reach the leaf node.

Select the leaf node with the highest product.

---

*Optionally*:

Along the way you /can/ optimize by traversing only the highest child of each node.

**Note** For this optimization we assume that no negative values exist.